# How can I make a checkerboard with variable size out of text in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, text

How can I make a checkerboard with variable size out of text? I can make a checkerboard consisting of single characters using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char C;
    int length;
    int width;
    int count = 0;
    int N;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    cout << "Input C" << endl;
    cin >> C;
    cout << "Input length" << endl;
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Input width" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Input N" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    for (row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
        if (row % 2 == 1) {
            for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
                {
                    cout << "-";
                }
                cout << "";
            }
        }
        for (col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
            for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
                {
                    cout << C;
                }
                cout << "";
            }
            if (col != N) {
                for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
                    {
                        cout << "-";
                    }
                    cout << "";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

But it only gives me an output of single characters, how would I added varying "block" sizes into the equation?

***For examaple,*** Given a character (C), a length (L), a width (W), and a size (N), write a C++ program   to draw a board of size (2N x 2N) consisting of cells filled up with character C, length of L, and width of W. The board cells have to be painted like a chess board

Assume  C   =   ‘&’,    L   =   4,  W   =   6,  and N   =   3

The output would be this (without the border lines)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQk2J.png]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I tried to look through your code and find the mistakes, but I ended up rewriting the problem from scratch. It's all about the nested loops, and you need quite some of them for fine-grained control.

The code that did the trick for me (I hope the comments are helpful):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    // Our variables
    char C;
    int L, W, N;
    // Take parameters from standard input
    std::cin >> C >> L >> W >> N;

    // Loop over all coarse rows
    for(int row = 0; row < 2*N; row++){
        // Loop over the fine rows
        for(int smallrow = 0; smallrow < L; smallrow++){
            // Loop over the coarse columns
            for(int col = 0; col < 2*N; col++){
                // Loop over the fine columns
                for(int smallcol = 0; smallcol < W; smallcol++){
                    // If col and row are both even or uneven, we color
                    if(row % 2 == col % 2){
                        std::cout << C;
                    }else{
                        std::cout << " ";
                    }

                }
            }
            // End of the small row, we need a new line
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ -o main main.cpp` and then executing with some parameters, for example `echo "X 3 5 2" | ./main` gives me a nice result:

```
XXXXX     XXXXX     
XXXXX     XXXXX     
XXXXX     XXXXX     
     XXXXX     XXXXX
     XXXXX     XXXXX
     XXXXX     XXXXX
XXXXX     XXXXX     
XXXXX     XXXXX     
XXXXX     XXXXX     
     XXXXX     XXXXX
     XXXXX     XXXXX
     XXXXX     XXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works, but I'd like to know how you approached the problem. What was your algorithm to solve this? I'd really like to know, thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a brute force algorithm. It cycles through every "cell" (C or " ") and decides what to paint it in. That's where the `row % 2 == col % 2` condition is important.

Answer (score 0):

The way to attack this kind of a problem is to decompose it into smaller problems, and keep decomposing the problem until you end up with very small tasks that can be easily translated into code.

For example, after reviewing your outline of what you're trying to do, one thing becomes abundantly clear:

Let's say we use the label "logical row" to refer to one or more physical rows of texts or strings that contain the image of one row in your checkerboard. In your example above, each logical row is made up of four physical rows. Then, the first thing that becomes abundantly clear that given any value of N, you're going to create N pairs of logical rows. In each pair, the first logical row will have the checkerboards in the odd columns, then the second logical row will have the checkerboard characters in the even columns.

So, we can confidently say that the code to do what you want will look something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < N; ++i)
{
    // Draw the odd checkboard logical row

    // Draw the even checkboard logical row
}
```

So, with N = 3 you're going to wind up with a checkerboard consisting of six rows, as in the example of your desired output. With N = 4, you'll get eight, and so on.

Now the problem is reduced, basically, to drawing a single logical checkerboard row. However it's going to turn out, the resulting code is going to get crammed into this for loop. So, we can set it aside.

The second easily decomposable step is that each checkerboard row consists of L lines of physical rows.

So, the code to produce a single logical checkerboard row would then look something like this:

```
for (int j=0; j<L; j++)
{
    // Draw a single line in a logical row.
}
```

This is done for each odd and even checkerboard row. Further on, to avoid code duplication, you could probably refine the final result, but for now it's sufficient to duplicate this for loop twice, inside the first for loop, once for the odd row, once for the even row.

At this step, the original problem is now decomposed into: draw a single physical row. This should be simple enough for you to borrow the code that you've already written, in your question, to implement the final answer.